# Inserting to schema-specific table with python's odo

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, blaze, odo

I'm using python's [odo](https://github.com/blaze/odo) to move data from a pandas dataframe to a postgresql database. The goal is that each "user" sees their own data in their schema, but with an identical data model and table/view naming schema between "users". With normal SQL I can do this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;
CREATE TABLE my_schema.my_table AS select 1;
```

My DB URI looks like this

```
db_uri = 'postgresql://localhost/postgres::my_schema.my_table'
```

This gives me tables in the `default` schema named "my_schema.my_table", including the '.' in the table name, instead of tables named "my_table" in the schema "my_schema".

I've tried different combinations based on this [github issue](https://github.com/blaze/odo/issues/220#issue-85638876), such as:

```
db_uri = 'postgresql://localhost/postgres.schema::tmp')
```

which gives me this Traceback

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  database "postgres/schema" does not exist
```

And also this one

```
db_uri = 'postgresql://localhost/postgres::my_schema/my_table'
```

which gives me tables named "my_schema/my_table".

Here's a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
from odo import odo
db_uri = 'postgresql://localhost/postgres::my_schema.my_table'
odo(pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1}, {'a': 1}]), db_uri)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden deep in a [mailing list for blaze](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/blaze-dev/HBSGexnDtuU/-_Y6h2S9CcUJ) is a mention of the `schema` parameter

```
d = Data(resource('postgresql://localhost/db::t', schema='myschema'))
```

which can be used with odo with the following format:

```
from odo import odo, drop
drop(db_uri, schema='my_schema') # to drop table in specific schema
odo(data, db_uri, schema='my_schema')
```

working code

```
import pandas as pd
from odo import odo
db_uri = 'postgresql://localhost/postgres::my_table'
odo(pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1}, {'a': 1}]), db_uri, schema='my_schema')
```

Comment: bummer that schema isn't part of the DB URI